# The SFMC Android Mobile Push SDK's Inbox, getMessages method is not providing the all inbox messages sent from SFMC dashboard response

Tags: android, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I'm using the SFMC Android Mobile Push SDK for Inbox messages in the Android app. I want to retrieve all inbox messages sent from the SFMC app dashboard and display them to the user. Currently, I'm attempting to fetch these inbox messages using the getMessages method provided by the Android Mobile Push SDK. However, I've noticed that it only returns messages sent after the user installs and logs into the app.

So how I can get all messages sent from the SFMC App dashboard?

I have followed the official documentation of SFMC cloud sdk-
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android

Below is the code that I am using to retrieve inbox messages.

```
SFMCSdk.requestSdk{sdk ->      sdk.mp{ mp ->           Log.d("TAG", "Inbox Messages ${mp.inboxMessageManager.messages}")      } }
```

I have tried with Mobile push SDK's getMessages method but it is only providing the inbox messages which were sent after the user installs the app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.